# Python 3.8 in Cygwin

Tags: python, cygwin, python3

I've been using Cygwin on a Windows 7 machine for a long time.
Recently trying to install a project from git and virtualenv defaults to python 2.7
I have python3.6m installed, but when I execute the python3 binary, nothing happens. Nothing.

Apparently it is the binary:

```
$ file /usr/bin/python3.8.exe
/usr/bin/python3.8.exe: PE32+ executable (console) x86-64, for MS Windows
```

I don't understand what's going on here.
Anyone have some insight other than a wild-ass guess?

**UPDATE 2020-07-09 21:24**

At this point the project and `virtualenv` are no longer the issue. My installation of python36 and 37 in cygwin is not responding to the call to execute.

```
$ python3
[33/5029] (user@MACHINE): 2020-07-09 21:22:03 /cygdrive/k/tmp
```

That's what it looks like.

This is what's in my cygwin installation:

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/pyth*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 User None   13 2018-02-13 03:58:20 /usr/bin/python -> python2.7.exe
lrwxrwxrwx 1 User None   13 2018-02-13 03:58:20 /usr/bin/python2 -> python2.7.exe
-rwxr-xr-x 1 User None 9235 2017-10-31 19:14:56 /usr/bin/python2.7.exe
lrwxrwxrwx 1 User None   14 2018-02-13 03:58:28 /usr/bin/python3 -> python3.6m.exe
lrwxrwxrwx 1 User None   14 2019-07-21 11:38:16 /usr/bin/python3.6 -> python3.6m.exe
-rwxr-xr-x 1 User None 9747 2019-07-21 11:38:23 /usr/bin/python3.6m.exe
-rwxr-xr-x 1 User None 9235 2020-05-23 06:57:40 /usr/bin/python3.8.exe
lrwxrwxrwx 1 User None   52 2018-05-08 22:15:21 /usr/bin/pythontex -> /usr/share/texmf-dist/scripts/pythontex/pythontex.py
```

I switch directly into the /usr/bin directory

```
$ u /usr/bin/
/usr/bin /cygdrive/k/tmp
[35/5031] (user@MACHINE): 2020-07-09 21:27:52 /usr/bin
$ ./python3.8.exe
[36/5032] (user@MACHINE): 2020-07-09 21:28:10 /usr/bin
$
```

This is a copy of the line by line output as anyone canne see from the history numbering.

Comment: Of course `/usr/bin/python3.8.exe` is python 3.8. How are you calling it ? Cygwin has available as packages python 2.7, 3.6, 3.7 and 3.8

Comment: Please consider [edit]ing your question to include the Git project you are attempting to use and how you are installing it, how you are invoking/using `virtualenv` and finally what you are actually attempting to execute and how (i.e. what file(s) and what command(s)).

Comment: I call it the same way you call any executable.

Comment: At this point the project and virtualenv are no longer the issue. My installation of python36 and 37 in cygwin is not responding to the call to execute.

Comment: I suspect you have some packages NOT updated as you have not stopped all process before an update. See guidance on https://cygwin.com/problems.html . You can followup up on the cygwin mailing list https://cygwin.com/lists.html

Comment: Maybe just need to repoint the symlinks? seems like pointing to these vs the newer versions you installed?
/usr/bin/python -> python2.7.exe
/usr/bin/python2 -> python2.7.exe
/usr/bin/python3 -> python3.6m.exe

Comment: I probably fixed this when I reinstalled cygwin on a new machine.